# return the Scanner inputs by calling the methods and return it to the public class value

Tags: java, methods, return-value

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UI {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int Store ,Week = play();

    public int play() {

           System.out.print(" Please enter the store #(1-6)");
           Store = input.nextInt();`

           System.out.print("please enter the operation (1-7)");
           Week = input.nextInt();

return Store,Week;
}

}
```

how can I possibly return Store and Week value into ui class. So I can use these values for further coding.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do a return like you do in java. You should change a return type of **play** to array if you want call this method to return two values.

My suggestion is to change **play** and call it from constructor.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UI {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int Store, Week;
    
    public UI() {
        play();
    }

    public void play() {
        System.out.print(" Please enter the store #(1-6)");
        Store = input.nextInt();`

        System.out.print("please enter the operation (1-7)");
        Week = input.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `play` method doesn't need to return a value.

If the values are fields, you can simply assign them from within the method.

```java
public class UI {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int store, week;

    void play() {
        System.out.print(" Please enter the store #(1-6)");
        store = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("please enter the operation (1-7)");
        week = input.nextInt();
    }
}
```